# $_GET variable depends on the redirect URL

Tags: php, facebook, redirect

I have the following website

http://localhost/showmecow/dashboard/

And inside I have a PHP script running from an Iframe.
The script is located at

http://localhost/showmecow/phpscript

I try to connect to FB, when I put the redirect URL as http://localhost/showmecow/phpscript it works fine, FB redirects back to this script with $_GET filled with code field and state field but now this script is shown on its own and not in the Iframe.

when I put the redirect URL as http://localhost/showmecow/dashboard/ it does not work, FB redirects back to the dashboard with empty $_GET and when I call getSessionFromRedirect it fails in isValidRedirect.

Any ideas on why it may happen?

Thanks

Comment: I have found the issue. http://localhost/showmecow/dashboard/ is a WordPress site, when I put a breakpoint in the WP code, I see the _GET I get from FB. However, when the script loads, it's already gone... any way to save this parameters to be used by the script?

Answer (score 0):

For Future reference, As I was saying in the comment, _GET was filled for the upper level which is the dashboard but not for the bottom level which is the PHP script in the Iframe. What I did is to save these parameters in the DB and extract them in the script.

I prefer that method because I have a membership DB which means each user gets a space.

If I didn't have it, I would have found a way to pass it to the script using command line argument.